# React js - Eliminar número 0 al inicio de un input type=["number"]

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando una app en React js, donde, necesito realizar la siguiente acción en los input type=["number"]; como tal, en los input carga un valor por defecto, los cuales pueden ser borrados para establecer otro número, sin embargo, en está parte se realiza una pequeña validación, la cual, consiste en que si el número ingresado es 0, se establecerá automáticamente el número 1. Pero sucede que al borrar el número previo, se establece automáticamente el número 1, y no permite borrarlo para cambiarlo.

Como tal lo que deseo realizar es que se pueda borrar el número preestablecido y cambiarlo por otro, pero validar que al escribir el número 0, se establezca automáticamente el 1; o en su efecto que al borrar se establezca el número 0, pero al ingresar un número, el 0 se borre. Muchas gracias.

Mi código es el siguiente.

```
const ProductCartItem = ({product, spec}) => {
    // Contexts
    const { productsToBuy, setProductsToBuy, setTotalPrice, numberGarments, setNumberGarments } = useContext(ProductsToBuyContext)
    // States
    const [totalPriceSpec, setTotalPriceSpec] = useState()
    const [newQty, setNewQty] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        /* Realiza una sumatoria de la cantidad de productos específicos solicitados, para obtener el preio total */
        let price = 0
        let garments = 0
        productsToBuy.map(product => {
            product.specs.map(spec => {
                price += (spec.qty*parseFloat(product.price))
                garments += parseInt(spec.qty)
                if (spec.qty !== parseInt(spec.qty)) spec.qty = 0
            })
        })
        setTotalPrice(price.toFixed(2))
        setNumberGarments(garments)
        if (newQty) {
            spec.qty = parseInt(newQty)
        }

        setTotalPriceSpec((parseFloat(product.price)*parseInt(spec.qty)).toFixed(2))
    }, [newQty, productsToBuy])

    const removeProduct = (id, productId) => {
        const newProductsToBuyList = [...productsToBuy]

        newProductsToBuyList.map(product => {
            product.specs = product.specs.filter(spec => spec.id !== id)
            setProductsToBuy(newProductsToBuyList)
            if (product.specs.length === 0) {
                setProductsToBuy(productsToBuy.filter(product => product.id !== productId))
            }
        })
             
        // console.log(newProductsToBuyList)
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        switch (e.target.name) {
            case spec.id:
                if (e.target.value <= 0) {
                    e.target.value = 1
                    spec.qty = e.target.value
                    setNewQty(e.target.value)
                }  else {
                    setNewQty(e.target.value)
                    spec.qty = e.target.value
                }
            break
        }
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <h1>{product.product}</h1>
                <div>
                    <span>Talla: {spec.size}</span>
                    <span>Color: {spec.color}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                    type="number"
                    name={spec.id}
                    value={spec.qty}
                    onChange={handleChange}  
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>${totalPriceSpec}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button 
                    onClick={() => {
                        removeProduct(spec.id, product.id)
                    }} 
                    title="Retirar Producto"
                >
                    <img src={deleteIcon} alt="" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}

export {ProductCartItem};
```